# Flutter Provider "uid was caled on null"

Tags: flutter, provider

I've been dabbing around with Flutter in the past months and damn I'm stuck on this one.

I want to set up a provider, that takes in an authenticated user's id, however whenever I run my app it gives me an error as:

> The getter 'uid' was called on null.

Here's my code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  AuthService _auth = new AuthService();
  TimerService _timer;
  User user;

  List<Timing> timers = [];

  initUser() async {
    await _auth.signInAnon();
    user = await _auth.currentUser();
    print("THE UID IS ${user.uid}");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //TODO: implement firebase data req
    return StreamProvider<List<Timing>>.value(
      value: TimerService(user.uid).timingStream,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Styles.backgroundColor,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateTimer()));
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.1,
          backgroundColor: Styles.backgroundColor,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.list),
              onPressed: () {
                //TODO
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    TimerList(),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it also throws another error consequently:

> Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.

Which is due to my usage of the provided data:

```
class TimerList extends StatefulWidget {
  TimerListState createState() => TimerListState();
}

class TimerListState extends State<TimerList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final timingStream = Provider.of<List<Timing>>(context);

    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: timingStream.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[TimerWidget(timingStream[index])],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Please explain to me why and how would be the correct way of giving the Provider the user's uid.
I apologize if I posted a bit too much code then required, rather be safe then sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Dart by default the value is null if you are not assigning any value
so User is null in your case so make a new object of it.

```
  User user=new User();
```

now if you want to use user instance then you can

```
initUser() async {
    await _auth.signInAnon();
    user = await _auth.currentUser();
    print("THE UID IS ${user.uid}");
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this cleared it up for me, I managed to do a workaround by using a FutureBuilder!